# Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS ethernet sudden stop working - network UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, drivers

I have a PC and just installed ubuntu for about 1 month. Everything worked will until now, the internet stopped. My router lights are on indicates that cable is connected in the device but the Network settings does not show any connection.

here is my response for :

`sudo lshw -C network`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCWz4.jpg)

and here is a screen shot for my network settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnJ1U.jpg)

output of :
`sudo modprobe r8169 && sudo dmesg | grep r81`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Uqo.jpg)

response for this command:
`sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu0fH.jpg)

I have been looking for hours and really appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169 && sudo dmesg | grep r81` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 just added it

Comment: May we also see, in an edit: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: @chili555 done too

Comment: If you boot into an earlier kernel at the GRUB menu, does the ethernet work? If so, we can fix this up quickly.

Comment: yup it does. IT works with kernel 5.13.0-44-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package *linux-modules-extra* seems to be missing in your 5.13.0-48-generic, possibly after an automatic update gone wrong.

While booted into 5.13.0-44-generic, please do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-48-generic
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

Comment: It did, Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate ti.